# WHEN you run self=[super init] and it returns nil, what is the correct response?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, null

I run this code in the instance of may class:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // my init code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

...and self returns nil.  I KNOW this is correct procedure and should be done. But if self were to return nil, what should my response be ?  Throw up an alert that the program has failed and is terminating ?  Ignore it ?  Or is there a recommended procedure to safely continue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it sounds recursive, but I think the best thing to do in this instance is to return the nil.

You cannot really predict what the state of the object is when getting a nil value returned from the initializer, so the safest thing to do is just dispose of the object.  From the initializer, that means just returning nil to the caller.

When alloc]init]ing, it always seemed to me like this situation would lead to leaks, so I've always been quite hesitant to simply call alloc]init] blindly.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen it happen personally. But since objc handles dealing with nil so well I wouldn't worry about having special cases beyond what you're already doing by returning the nil you received from the super.

Comment: I see it as a fault of Objective-C lets you send messages to nil.  That means that you can run out of memory and not find out about it until a long time later, when you don't know how to handle the problem gracefully.

Comment: How are you going to run out of memory exactly?

Comment: @Don Returning nil from the -init method is the indication that something failed in the initialization process. If you're out of memory, +alloc will return nil and -init never gets called. I prefer the Objective-C paradigm. You don't have to worry about a NULL pointer exception every time you forget to check the return value when you create a new object or when you receive an object as a method parameter. You only have to explicitly check the ones that matter in your app.